# Xcode/iTunes/Instruments central toolbar item; what's it called and how do I create one?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, itunes, toolbar

I'd like to create a toolbar item like the central item seen in Xcode/iTune/Instruments/etc:

[image: central toolbar item]

Can anyone tell me what it's called and how to go about creating my own?

Also, will I face problems getting my app approved by Apple when I submit it to the Mac App Store, for imitating Apple's own apps too much?

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but it seems plausible to create a toolbar, then make your own custom view to imitate what you want.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer I agree. Any idea what Apple call this view?

Comment: Not sure.  I guess it wouldn't really matter anyways.  It's up to what you want to do with it.

Comment: It's a custom control built into some private framework for use by Apple apps. It should be perfectly fine (and probably easier than you think) to create your own for your app.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Ok thanks - I'll have a crack at it then.

Comment: @trojanfoe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951196/itunes-style-box-in-cocoa might help

Comment: @Damien good find - many thanks. This question can be closed as a duplicate, but I don't seem able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally implemented the solution from here:

[iTunes or Xcode style information box at top of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951196/itunes-style-box-in-cocoa)

Here are the initial results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an Apple's private control, but you cannot create it as a NSToolbarItem. Check this other Q/A to know how to add a custom view in the window's main frame.

[Is it possible to draw in the label area of NSToolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169255/is-it-possible-to-draw-in-the-label-area-of-nstoolbar)

Comment: That isn't true - I've created the control using the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951196/itunes-style-box-in-cocoa.  I have added it to the toolbar and even got it centred correctly.

Comment: @trojanfoe: the code snippet at the link you provided doesn't use NSToolbarItem and NSToolbar: it overrides the NSView's drawRect: method to draw a custom box. What I am stating in my answer is that iTunes and Xcode don't use a NSToolbarItem to display their LCDs, as they are drawing in the toolbar item's label area.

Comment: Yes apparently they draw *over* the toolbar using separate window.  I don't want to do that as it sounds too ugly to me...

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some interesting things about Instruments:

- If you make the window narrow such that the overflow menu is triggered, the items in that menu are all blank.
- You can't change the icon size or turn labels on/off.
- Colors does not have a label when you add it to the toolbar.
- The labels on Space, Flexible Space, and Colors do not line up with the other items' labels.

These are interesting because they seem to fit an idea I had for implementing this: turn labels off, and give *all* your items custom views, where normal-looking items actually have manually drawn labels. It would obviously be a lot of work, but it gives you enough freedom to effectively do full-height items.

The nice thing is that, unlike the view/window hack that Xcode seems to use, you still have a customizable toolbar with draggable items.